# What is the difference between 蔵, 倉, and 庫?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, kanji, kanji-choice

The word 【くら】 can be written with any of the kanji 蔵, 倉, or 庫. However, [WWWJDIC](http://wwwjdic.mygengo.com/cgi-data/wwwjdic?1MDJ%C1%D2) lists them all under one entry, defined as:

> (n) warehouse; cellar; magazine; granary; godown; depository; treasury; elevator;

Is there a difference in nuance or usage between these three kanji, and if so, what?

**Update:** @istrasci points out that:

> [When] 蔵 is used as【〜ぞう】in compounds, it's used to denote ownership or possession.
>
> Whereas compounds with 庫 seem to refer more to a physical storage facility.

Does anybody know about different nuances of the word 【くら】 itself?

Comment: https://japanthis.com/2017/11/30/kura-all-about-japanese-storehouses/ - Here is an article in english about what a kura is, it is a traditional kind of storehouse. I find them nostalgic since a kura is featured in hikaru no go

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's what a person who's been immersed in the Japanese culture for 22 years imagine when she sees them without much context.

### 蔵

[image: picture of 蔵]

- Where it can be found: In the estate of an old family, or as a cellar of a sake brewery. Usually in a place crowded with other buildings (hence the backside of the kura is blurred in the picture).
- What's inside: Something valuable, treasures, or simply old and unused things for special occassions.
- Height: 2-3 stories.

### 倉

[image: picture of 倉]

- Where: In the rural districts.
- What's inside: Farming tools, stored rice and unused things (of everyday use).
- Height: 1-2 stories.

### 庫

[image: picture of 庫]

Note: I didn't know 庫 can be read as くら. These are the impressions I have about the kanji itself.

- Where: In a house or any other building, or as a part of one.
- What's inside: Something valuable, or other trinkets. Usually contains a single type of things.
- Height: Can vary in size. Usually box-shaped and smaller than 倉.

Comment: Did you draw all by yourself? Neat! It's not plain MS-Paint.

Comment: I see you got some inspiration from Google image search ;)

Answer (score 8):

As far as using them strictly for the word 【くら】, I'm not sure of any nuances.  But when 蔵 is used as【〜ぞう】in compounds, it's used to denote ownership or possession.

> 私蔵　【しぞう】　→　Private collection
>   家蔵　【かぞう】　→　Household collections
>   所蔵　【しょぞう】→　To have in your possession (== 所有)
>   蔵書　【ぞうしょ】→　Collection of books / a library

Whereas compounds with 庫 seem to refer more to a physical storage facility.

> 車庫　【しゃこ】　→　Garage
>   金庫　【きんこ／かねぐら】　→　Vault/treasury
>   武器庫【ぶきこ】　→　Armory

Still the meanings seem to overlap even in a lot of compound words.

Comment: Very interesting. I hadn't noticed the compound-based meanings... but you're right, it's not entirely straight-forward with compounds, especially with words like 冷蔵庫【れいぞうこ】.

Answer (score 4):

**新選漢和辞典第六版付録同訓異義要覧八七頁**

> ## 【くら】
>
> **〔倉〕**
>
> 米【こめ】ぐら。穀物【こくもつ】ぐら。
>
> **〔蔵〕**
>
> 大切【たいせつ】なものをしまっておく所【ところ】。
>
> **〔庫〕**
>
> 武器【ぶき】や車【くるま】をおさめる所【ところ】。
>
> **〔府〕**
>
> 金【かね】や品物【しなもの】をしまう所【ところ】。
>
> **〔廩〕**
>
> 米【こめ】ぐら。屋根【やね】のあるくら。

I still think it should be called 同義異訓要覧.